# How to uninstall "Logi Options" utility software in macOS 11.5 Big Sur?

Tags: macos, security

I have given up on trying to use my new *Logitech Trackman Marble*, as it not recognized by the [*Logi Options*](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893) utility software I downloaded from Logitech. With no way to adjust the speed of the pointer, and no way to change behaviors of the buttons, the device is useless.

Specificaly, I don’t see a way to revoke the permissions I gave in the *Accessibility* pane of *System Preferences* during that install process.  I see no such pane now with a checkbox list of products.

How can I uninstall *Logi Options*?

Comment: Do you not have the "Logi Options Uninstaller" in your **Applications** > **Utilities** folder?

Comment: @agarza Bingo! Thanks. The uninstaller did indeed remove the two items from *System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *Accessibility* > *Privacy* that I mentioned. Do you want to make an Answer of that for me to accept?

Comment: I know Logitech control center is not supported in Big Sur, and your mouse (older or cheaper) uses it if it doesn’t use logi options. This is the logi blog post: https://blog.logitech.com/2020/11/10/update-on-logitech-control-center-lcc-software-with-macos-11-big-sur-what-does-this-mean-for-you/

Comment: Upon checking on my mac with an old logi mouse, you can still use LCC with no problems at all in mid-2021 on Big Sur. Maybe you'll be able to use your marble mouse after all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Logitech provides an uninstaller with the original software install.

You can find in in **Applications** > **Utilities** > **Logi Options Uninstaller**.

This should remove any and all of the Logitech software including the uninstaller itself.